# React native widget Android/IOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, widget

I need to create widget to screen on Android and IOS with ReactNative. This widget must cat sends requests to server and displaying some information. Can I create widget with RractNative? Or can I make this widget to connecting with app (also made with ReactNative).